# the_post_thumbnail() based on the Post ID

Tags: php, functions, post-meta, homepage, single

This is How a code in single.php looks like →

But needed that in homepage so I decided to make code based on the post ID →

```
 <?php $fpid = get_theme_mod('kirki_fpid'); ?>
```

(The above is fetching the Post ID)

and

```
<?php $imv = get_post_meta($fpid, 't_vid_base', true); ?>
```

Now comes it's implementation→

The code in single.php →

## 1

```
if(certain condition true) {
  $url = esc_url( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 't_oembed', 1 ) );

    echo wp_oembed_get( $url );  
}
```

and

## 2

```
if(certain condition true) {   
    the_post_thumbnail( 'large'); 
}
```

## The #1 can be converted to be usable for home page(based on POST ID) like this →

```
if(certain condition true) {
  $url = esc_url( get_post_meta( $fpid, 't_oembed', 1 ) );    
    echo wp_oembed_get( $url );  
}
```

## Question →

How to make the second one based on the POST ID(`$fpid`)? that means  this(`the_post_thumbnail( 'large');` ) should render results based on POST ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution so self-answering the question for future users/visitors.
Hope it will help someone.

I think this won't be able to generate results based on the Post ID →

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'large');
```

However, this should work →

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($fpid, 'large'); ?>
```

(Above is succesfully tested)

**Other possibilities →**

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($fpid, 'thumbnail'); ?>
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($fpid, 'medium'); ?>
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($fpid, 'full'); ?>
```

If you want to use **the hardcoded POST ID** then this should work →

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail('311', 'large'); ?>
```

**Other possibilities(Hard Coded POST ID) →**

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail('311', 'thumbnail'); ?>
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail('311', 'medium'); ?>
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail('311', 'full'); ?>
```

> P.S. → 311 is a post ID, for example.
>
> $fpid → User selected POST ID(Post selected form the Theme customizer
>   settings)

I hope this should be helpful to someone in future.